# How can I read my Heroku application's past logs?

Tags: logging, heroku, ip

I have a web app in Heroku (J2EE + Angular 2).

I would like to know if it is possible to see all the historical logs (for example, from the last 14 days) on Heroku. How does this work?

The only information that I need now is all the unique IP addresses that have accessed my webapp (without installing any specific add-on).

Comment: Why do you not want to install an add-on? There are many logging add-ons, and I'd recommend using one of those.

Comment: You are right. But I didn't do it for the 7 previous day. Now I have an add-on. But how to retrieve the previous log or ip adress ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`heroku logs` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs) to view your logs. But note that [Heroku only saves the latest 1500 lines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits). If you haven't saved them yourself anything beyond that will be gone.